# DataMember could not be found

Tags: c#, rest, windows-mobile

As I have done my research regarding this problem of mine, I still have no luck in solving my error of Error    1 **The type or namespace name 'DataMember' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I have come across a solution stating that I should reference **System.Runtime.Serialization** but still I am having no luck even when add reference to it.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WebServApp
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int EmpNo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int DeptNo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the tutorial that I am actually trying to follow:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=472

Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: not working even you add System.Runtime.Serialization?

Comment: still not working even if I add System.Runtime.Serialization using Add Reference in the menu or by typing "using System.Runtime.Serialization"

Comment: What version of the CompactFramework are you building against? Could be it's only available in 3.5?

Comment: I am using CompactFramework 3.5

Comment: check your framework version.

Comment: Does your web server have Serialization in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
I just removed the System.Runtime.Serialization in the references in the project explorer and addded it by browsing then it worked. Weird.

Comment: Yes, you wrote [Serializable] instead of DataContract . Org:[DataContract(Name = "Employee", Namespace = "")]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public int EmpNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int DeptNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}. Sometimes copy and paste is your friend.

Comment: Nope. The [Serializable] wasnt the problem. I just did what I did on my answer above. When it worked, I actually removed the [Serializble] in the code but it still worked.

Answer (score 25):

Remove `System.Runtime.Serialization` from code, then add from **menu > Project > Add reference** ..> . Then again add into code. it works.

Comment: Once you're in the Reference Manager, you'll find System.Runtime.Serialization under the Assemblies > Framework tab.