# AirConsole Unity plugin gives compiler error - 'DataContractAttribute' could not be found

Tags: unity-game-engine, airconsole

I'm trying to compile my AirConsole project in Monodevelop so I can debug it.

It gives a compiler error from the included 'Newtonsoft.JSON' library:

```
The type or namespace name `DataMemberAttribute' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp)
```

The project builds fine running from Unity; this error only happens when you try to hit "Run" in Monodevelop, to enable the debugger.

Is there an easy way to fix this error?

Comment: These threads describe the same problem (and solutions):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687315/datamember-could-not-be-found

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401795/namespace-for-datacontract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment above: for Monodevelop, find the **References** folder in the root folder of your solution, right-click it, and choose **Edit**.

In the window that comes up, search for **System.Runtime.Serialization** and add it to your references. This will let you build and debug your Unity project.